# How to populate a pandas dataframe (dfA) column "A" with values from another dataframe (dfB), depending on column / row values from dfB?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df (dfA) with the life expectancy at birth and gdp per year of 6 countries.  with the following [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RevK9.png):

```
country  year  expectancy  gdp  difference
chile    2000    60       1bn     NA
chile    2001    63       1.5bn  0.5bn
chile    2002    65       2.5bn  0.5bn
chile    2003    68       3.5bn  1.0bn
  .
  .
  .
chile    2015    80      10bn     10bn
```

Each row represents the data (gdp, expectancy, etc) for a country per year, spanning from the year 2000 to 2015 and with 6 countries.

I have created a new dataframe to store important overall variables per country, such as GDP delta (GDP in 2015 minus GDP in 2000) per country. The new df (dfB) looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5Kp9.png):

```
country   startEndDelta (dummydata)
Chile        x
China        y
Germany      z
Mexico       a
USA          b
Zimbabwe     c
```

What I want to do is add a new column to my newdf that shows which year had the greatest increase in GDP for each country.

I was already able to calcualte the year but I first had to create another dataframe with records from only one country. [Here I do it the way I metioned before.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsfhH.png)

The way I wish to do this would be something similar to:

```
dfB['biggestDeltaYear'] = ?year with the biggest increase in GDP?
```

Where this single line of code populates every row in dfB for my new column 'biggestDeltaYear'.

What are my options?

**Thank you very much**

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try use the groupby() method of pandas.DataFrame

```
dfA.groupby('country').apply(lambda x:x['year'].iloc[x['difference'].argmax()])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option:

```
dfA['biggestDeltaYear'] = (dfA.iloc[dfA.groupby('country')['difference']
                           .apply(lambda x: x.argmax())]['year'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this using groupby and apply lambda operations in Pandas. Below is an example I drew:

Consider the following data:

```
Country,Year,GDP
Chile,2011,1.5
Chile,2012,1
Chile,2013,2
Chile,2014,2.3
Chile,2015,3.2
Nigeria,2011,0.6
Nigeria,2012,0.9
Nigeria,2013,2.1
Nigeria,2014,2.2
Nigeria,2015,2.6
Australia,2011,10.4
Australia,2012,14.4
Australia,2013,12.3
Australia,2014,13.3
Australia,2015,15
```

First, we apply the diff operation country wise:

```
df['diff'] = df.groupby("Country")["GDP"].transform(pd.DataFrame.diff)

    Country     Year    GDP     diff
0   Chile       2011    1.5     NaN
1   Chile       2012    1.0     -0.5
2   Chile       2013    2.0     1.0
3   Chile       2014    2.3     0.3
4   Chile       2015    3.2     0.9
5   Nigeria     2011    0.6     NaN
6   Nigeria     2012    0.9     0.3
7   Nigeria     2013    2.1     1.2
8   Nigeria     2014    2.2     0.1
9   Nigeria     2015    2.6     0.4
10  Australia   2011    10.4    NaN
11  Australia   2012    14.4    4.0
12  Australia   2013    12.3    -2.1
13  Australia   2014    13.3    1.0
14  Australia   2015    15.0    1.7
```

Then we can generate a boolean column based on the largest value:

```
df['biggestDeltaYear'] = df.groupby("Country")['diff'].apply(lambda x:x==x.max())
    Country     Year    GDP     diff    biggestDeltaYear
0   Chile       2011    1.5     NaN     False
1   Chile       2012    1.0     -0.5    False
2   Chile       2013    2.0     1.0     True
3   Chile       2014    2.3     0.3     False
4   Chile       2015    3.2     0.9     False
5   Nigeria     2011    0.6     NaN     False
6   Nigeria     2012    0.9     0.3     False
7   Nigeria     2013    2.1     1.2     True
8   Nigeria     2014    2.2     0.1     False
9   Nigeria     2015    2.6     0.4     False
10  Australia   2011    10.4    NaN     False
11  Australia   2012    14.4    4.0     True
12  Australia   2013    12.3    -2.1    False
13  Australia   2014    13.3    1.0     False
14  Australia   2015    15.0    1.7     False
```

The actual year values can also be obtained instead of boolean using:

```
df['Year'][df.groupby("Country")['diff'].apply(lambda x:x==x.max())]
```

or,

```
df.iloc[df.groupby("Country")['diff'].apply(lambda x:x.idxmax())]['Year']
```

HTH.